# The installer of an installer

Tags: neologisms, morphology, derivational-morphology

This is probably one of many questions brought forward by this computing age; but what can I call a person who installs an installer?

I was thinking `installee`, which isn't a word given we already had installer for "someone installing *something*", but now the something being installed is itself referred to as the installer [of the resultant software]!

So forgetting the current status of installee (and only if no answers end up being "oh, here's a word that you overlooked which does mean what you want");
is "installee" morphologically sound, can I help coin it to mean "one who uses an installer"?

If I was to write-

```
Use bob.com to download the CoolPlugin installer.
The installee must then ensure all documents are saved before continuing.
```

-would it make sense to you?

Comment: Obviously, the "installerer".

Comment: I would say "installee" means that which is installed.  Just as an employee is the one who is employed.

Comment: I guess for that analogy the thinking was "the employee commences the [employer's] employment" -> "the installee commences the [installer's] installation". Like, the -ee is the instigator of an action, in this case duties/running a program, instead of being the object affected by the action

Comment: An installer installs things - it doesn't matter if they install radiators or installers - They're an installer.

Comment: *Installees* scares me. Who is using the software? Not installees, but developers or techies.Take a cue from your first word, the imperative *Use* in the second person. Don't call your customer names, but continue with, "Ensure that you save all documents before continuing."

Comment: @Greybeard they're running an installer, I don't think they're actually doing the installation *work* (that's why the installer is called the installer)

Comment: @YosefBaskin mm, so it looks like `installee` is bunk. That sentense was an example, I dont have customers. The sentence is more third person, so `you` would not be appropriate. With that now, back to the first part of the question; what can I use instead?

Comment: It’s not a unique problem. Early on the questions occurred whether the operator of a typewriter was called a typewriter, and so with a computer. Eventually distingishing terms developed. Consider engineer or IT professional for the person rather than the hardware or software on which they work.

Comment: @Xanne that's a good perspective. I took a look at the wiki page to see what they had done. Predictably people used `user`, `operator`, and `typist`. Perhaps the word is just not important enough to warrant a variant with this nuance to it (where `typist` is a full profession). I suppose if doing this sort of thing was a big part of the person (like their job) you'd just use "[IT] administrator"